# How can I make it so that if a member repeats text sent by my bot, my bot sends a message back?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make a competition type event where my bot generates a random number and if a member replies with the same number the bot sends a new message congratulating them.

All I have so far is the number generator and I am not sure how I can make my bot know when the same number is sent.

Here is everything I have so far:

````
client.on('message', function(message) { 
console.log(message.content);
});

client.on("ready", function() {
console.log("Ready");
});

var code = Math.floor(Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() * 992875 + Math.random());

if (message.content === 'start competition') {
channel.send('Please repeat these numbers: ' + code); 
};

client.login('token');```
````

Comment: Are you inside a `client.on('message', msg => {`? Provide more information please, the only thing that help us is the tag "discord", that's it. Is not much to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code into the message event like:

```
let code;

client.on('message', function(
    if (message.content === 'start competition') {
        code = Math.floor(Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() * 992875 + Math.random());
        message.channel.send('Please repeat these numbers: ' + code); 
    } else if ( message.content == code) {
        message.channel.send('Congratulations, ' + message.author + ' you won');
        code = -1;
    }
});

client.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("Ready");
});


client.login('token');
```